# Invalid preceding regular expression git secret

Tags: git, windows-10, git-secret

I am trying to use awslabs/git-secrets on windows. When I add regex like 
`(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@$%&*]).{8,}`
and try to scan it throws an fatal error **Invalid preceding regular expression**. After trying to understand cause of error I found that if **(?** are wrote together it throws an error. I am trying to add regex for validating password with one uppercase,lowercase,digit and special character.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please give some examples of good and bad passwords?

Comment: @ElpieKay Strong Passwords - @oUx24z^0!D, Sjc7&%nd0 combination of one uppercase,lowercase,digit and speical char with min length of 8